# contentful/vault: Code compilation failed after Gradle plugin update to 8.2.2

Tags: android, gradle

I am using [contentful/vault lib](https://github.com/contentful/vault) for "Contentful.com" CMS data persistent in my Android app.

lib version :3.2.6

After updating the Gradle plugin version to 8.2.2 My code stopped compiling with below error:

> class com.contentful.vault.compiler.Processor (in unnamed module @0x434708e4) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Attribute (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x434708e4

how to fix it?

Comment: It might be that that library does not support a newer gradle version. Worthwhile to open an issue.